# pytorch split gives wrong answer

Tags: split, pytorch, torch

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(2, 3)
print(x)
splitted = x.split(split_size=2, dim=0)  # should get 2 tensors of 1 x 3  and 1 x 3 size I thought
print(splitted) #instead, get a tuple of len 1, with [0] =  tensor same as input
print(type(splitted), len(splitted))
print(splitted[0].shape)
print(torch.__version__)
```

gives the following output:

```
tensor([[0.0702, 0.1275, 0.3735],
        [0.0260, 0.9393, 0.9448]])
(tensor([[0.0702, 0.1275, 0.3735],
        [0.0260, 0.9393, 0.9448]]),)
<class 'tuple'> 1
torch.Size([2, 3])
1.3.1
```

Why do I not get two tensors in a tuple? I would have expected the input to be split in two. I am under Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You probably misinterpreted the [`split(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.split) documentation. It says:

> [...]
>
> - **split_size_or_sections (int) or (list(int))** – size of a single chunk or list of sizes for each chunk

Using `split`, the correct approach would be:

```py
import torch
x = torch.rand(2, 3)
splitted = x.split(split_size=1, dim=0)
```

To proceed as you wanted, you should use [`chunk(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.chunk) instead:

```py
import torch
x = torch.rand(2, 3)
chunks = x.chunk(chunks=2, dim=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior is as expected. Note that the parameter is `split_size` and not the number of splits. So you are specifying the size of the split. You have specified size to be 2, and your first dimension is size 2, so you get a tuple with one element (which is the all of `x`).

To get the desired effect, use `x.split(split_size=1, dim=0)`

See: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.split